# Limit results based on the dates of a related table

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have two tables, one is an events table, and one is an event_dates table.

What I want to do, is limit the amount of results from my events based on the event_dates. eg: If the current date is passed the last date for the event, it doesn't get returned.

Currently I have this:

```
$events = Events::with(['dates'=>function($query)
            {
                $query->orderBy('event_date','asc');
            }])->get();

return response()->json($events);
```

This will give me a json array with a "dates" array ascending. Is there a way to use the last row in that array in the where clause of the Events query?

Comment: You're looking for `whereHas`. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations

Comment: I saw that but I didn't think it did what I was looking to do. Maybe I don't understand it. Could you provide an example? I thought whereHas would return only if there were dates period.

Comment: Actually I think I see how it works now. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Too late now I wrote an answer already ;)

Comment: Haha. Well, I can accept your answer and give you precious internet points for that. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. And yay!! more internet points :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whereHas` with the right condition should work:

```
$today = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
$events = Events::whereHas('dates', function($q) use ($today){
    $q->where('event_date', '>=', $today);
})->get();
```

And obviously just add `with()` to that if you still want to eager load the relationship...